# android twitter integration exception

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

i want to integration a twitter in my application,
this is my code:

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Constants
    /**
     * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
     * consumer key and secret
     * */
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "<my key>";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "<my secure key>";

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter;
    // Update status button
    Button btnUpdateStatus;
    // Logout button
    Button btnLogoutTwitter;
    // EditText for update
    EditText txtUpdate;
    // lbl update
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // All UI elements
        btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
        btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
        btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
        txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
        lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
        lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);
        /**
         * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
         * */
        btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call login twitter function
                loginToTwitter();
            }
        });

        /**
         * This if conditions is tested once is redirected from twitter page.
         * Parse the uri to get oAuth Verifier
         * */
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                // oAuth verifier
                String verifier = uri
                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    Log.e("Twitter Login ... >", 0+"");

                    // Get the access token
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                            requestToken, verifier);

                    Log.e("Twitter Login ... >", 1+"");

                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                    Log.e("Twitter Login ... >", 2+"");

                    // After getting access token, access token secret
                    // store them in application preferences
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    // Store login status - true
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit(); // save changes

                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                    // Hide login button
                    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Show Update Twitter
                    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Getting user details from twitter
                    // For now i am getting his name only
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();

                    Log.e("Twitter Login ... >", 3+"");

                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();

                    Log.e("Twitter Login ... >", 4+"");

                    // Displaying in xml ui
                    lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username
                            + "</b>"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Check log for login errors
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to login twitter
     * */
    private void loginToTwitter() {
        new myConnection().execute(1);
    }

    /**
     * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
     * fetched from Shared Preferences
     * */
    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    class myConnection extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // Check if already logged in
            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Configuration configuration = builder.build();

                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                twitter = factory.getInstance();

                try {
                    requestToken = twitter
                            .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // user already logged into twitter

            }
            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```

The `Log` prints `Twitter Login ... > 0` and then an exception happened , i catch and print this statment

```
Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
```

the `e.getMessage()` is `null`

#### any help would be appreciated

Comment: i think you are getting your access token mismatch otherwise not create a problem..

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the CallbackURL. You need to put some coding for handling the WebView. SO that after redirecting from the twitter.!! Check the code that i given below.!!

I set up Twitter user authentication as in the tutorial above such that the Activity doing the Twitter authentication has its content view changed to a WebView, the Activity is declared in the manifest file containing an intent-filter to catch the Twitter callback and, on callback, the response is processed and the Activity's content view is changed back to whatever it was.

I got it working but in doing so I found (what I think is) an easier way and such that the WebView doesn't ever kick off the phone's web browser app (thereby leaving your app, which you don't really want), as follows:

(1) Remove the Activity singleInstance and intent-filter declarations you added to the manifest file (in following the tutorial above). Don't need that anymore!

(2) Add a WebView to your Activity layout file and set its initial visibility to "gone" and its position, height, width etc however you want it. I set its properties so that it covers the whole screen when visible, as follows:

```
<WebView
  android:id="@+id/myWebView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:visibility="gone" />
```

(3) Get a handle to your WebView in your Activity and set its WebViewClient to pick up the Twitter callback (and not to kick off the web browser app at any time), as follows...

```
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
      {
        if (url != null
            && url.startsWith("myapptwittercallback:///myapp"))
          handleTwitterCallback(url);
        else
          webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }

});
```

... Here you might also want to enable other settings of your WebView like saving form data and javascript execution (e.g. myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);)

(4) Make your WebView visible and focused at the point you need to do Twitter authentication, as follows:

```
try
{
  twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
  twitter.setOAuthConsumer(
      myTwitterConsumerKey,
      myTwitterConsumerSecret);
  twitterRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(
      "myapptwittercallback:///myapp");
  myWebView.loadUrl(
      twitterRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
  myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
catch (TwitterException ex)
{
  Toast.makeText(
      this,
      "Login failed. Please try again.",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

... Remember to clear your WebView's history (i.e. myWebView.clearHistory() and set its visibility to "gone" in your handleTwitterCallback(String) method.

(5) Lastly, override your Activity's onBackPressed() method so that your WebView handles presses of the back button if its visible, as follows...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  if (myWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
  {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack())
    {
      myWebView.goBack();
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      myWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      return;
    }
  }
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

That's it! You should now have Twitter integration in your app and the user should never leave your app in doing Twitter authentication.